# OpenOffice Automation on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7.5, openoffice

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET application which is intend to convert .doc, .docx, .xls and .xlsx files to PDF.  We are attempting to do this through a third party library which makes use of OpenOffice to achieve this.

I have deployed a small console application which works correctly however I have also deployed an ASP.NET application which uses the same code but cannot convert office documents to PDFs.  To me this indicates some configuration issue on the server but I have no idea what.

I've looked at the event log on the server and have found and entry with the message:

> The server {82154420-0FBF-11D4-8313-005004526AB4} did not register
>   with DCOM within the required timeout.

I can confirm that the GUID in that message is for OpenOffice on the server.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to configure IIS to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical that after hours of scratching my head and a couple of minutes after posting the question that I get it to work.

My AppPool uses the LocalSystem identity and in Component Services I changed the OpenOffice.org Service Manager to use the "Interactive User" as its identity.  It just worked after that!

Comment: The DCOM event error posted in the question doesn't seem to relate directly to the problem.